# Inverse restriction for polar coordinates in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions, inverse-function-theorem

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding why they set the domain and range ($U$ and $V$) as such. Because normally, if it's polar coordinates in one-dimension, you would set $0<\theta<\pi/2$ such that when you take the inverse of the function, it will still remain one-to-one.

How would letting $|\theta|<\pi$ in the domain and exclusion of $(x,0):x≤0$ in the range still let the function be a bijection when we restrict it like that?

Comment: You're thinking of an entirely different function.  In order to define $\sin^{-1}$, you need a domain where $\sin$ is $1-1.$  But here you need to pick up all $4$ quadrants of the Cartesian plane, and for that you either need to let $\theta$ range over an interval of size $2 \pi$ or you need to allow $r$ to take on negative values.

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by "a domain where sin is 1 - 1", you mean [-1, 1], right?

Comment: I mean one-to-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that by definition bijective = injective + surjective. Currently, the map $f$ is defined as follows, $f:\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$,
\begin{equation}
f(r,\theta) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
r \cos \theta \\
r \sin \theta
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
So far there is no restriction on the domain and target space of $f$. It's easy to see that $f$ is not even injective, because
$f(1,0) = f(1,2 \pi)$, yet $(1,0) \neq (1,2 \pi)$. Hence it can't be bijective. In this case, injectivity is an issue of the domain of the function, because the trigonometric functions $\sin,\cos$ are periodic with period $2 \pi$. So, what those notes are suggesting is that if you restrict the domain of $f$ to
\begin{equation}
U_1:= \{(r,\theta) \in \Bbb{R}^2: r>0 \quad \text{and} \quad -\pi < \theta < \pi\}
\end{equation}
then $f$ is injective. Recall that to prove $f$ is injective on $U$, you need to show that for every pair of points $\xi,\eta \in U$, if $f(\xi) = f(\eta)$, then $\xi = \eta$ (try to prove this yourself).

So, now the function with restricted domain $f: U_1 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ is injective. However, it is not surjective, because its range is not the entire $\Bbb{R}^2$. Note that $f[U_1]$ only contains those points in $\Bbb{R}^2$, which do not lie on the non-negative horizontal axis. In other words, the range of $f:U_1 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ is the set $V_1$ defined by
\begin{equation}
V_1 := f[U_1] =  \Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(x,0) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x \leq 0\}
\end{equation}
So, now if we restrict the codomain from $\Bbb{R}^2$ to $V_1$, it will become surjective, and hence bijective. Thus, what your notes are claiming is that the function $f:U_1 \to V_1$ is bijective (explicitly write out a proof for injectivity and surjectivity separately if it isn't obvious to you).

Lastly, your notes also claim that $U_1$ and $V_1$ are open subsets of $\Bbb{R}^2$, thereby making $f:U_1 \to V_1$ a $C^1$ diffeomorphism.

---

Also, as your notes remark, this choice of $U_1$, $V_1$ is not unique. There are other possible restrictions you can place on the domain and codomain of $f:\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$, to make it bijective. For instance, I think the most common one is
\begin{align}
U_2 &:= \{(r,\theta) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : r> 0 \quad \text{and} \quad 0< \theta < 2\pi\} \\
V_2 &:= f[U_2] =  \Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(x,0) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x \geq 0\}
\end{align}
Another choice (which is geometrically unnatural, so no one would use it in practice) is
\begin{align}
U_3 &:= \{(r,\theta) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : r< 0 \quad \text{and} \quad 2\pi< \theta < 4\pi\} \\
V_3 &:= f[U_3] =  \Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(x,0) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x \leq 0\}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, and I understand why we restrict domain as such now. However, I am wondering why we would restrict the range such that $\mathbb{R^2} \backslash \{(x,0)\in\mathbb{R^2}: x≤0\}$. When $\theta$ is zero, $y$ would be zero. As well as when $cos(\theta)$ is positive, our $x$ would be positive. So why would $V$ be defined as $f[U]$, since the restrictions wouldn't hold anymore?

Comment: Exactly, when $\theta = 0$, $(x,y)$ lies on the (strictly) positive $x$-axis. What we have removed is the non-negative $x$-axis, because that doesn't lie in the image of $f$.

Comment: Oops, I had it opposite. How about when $cos(\theta)$ is negative, then the restrictions would not hold?

Comment: Anyway, in general (not just for this question), if $f: A \to B$ is any function, then the image/range of $f$ is by definition $f(A)$. This is a subset of the codomain $B$. By definition, $f$ is surjective if $f(A) = B$.  Note that $f:A \to B$ may or may not be surjective, but if we restrict the codomain to the range, i.e we consider $f: A \to f(A)$, then this new function is surjective. This is what we're doing in your example. We're simply saying: ok currently the codomain is $\Bbb{R}^2$, and it's too big, let's just restrict the codomain to be equal to the range, so that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: In your example, there is no value of $\theta$ in the interval $-\pi < \theta < \pi$ such that $\cos \theta < 0$ and $\sin \theta = 0$, so I'm not really sure what your question is

Comment: So, if I let $cos(\theta)$ = $cos(-2\pi/3)$, then our $x$ would be negative, then it wouldn't satisfy the range's restriction, even though $f: A\to f(A)$ is supposed to be surjective, where $A$ is the restricted domain.

Comment: $x$ is negative but $y$ is not $0$ (because $\sin(-2\pi/3) < 0$), so it does satisfy the range restriction. The crucial thing is we cannot have $x<0$ AND $y=0$. What we're doing is only removing the non-negative $x$-axis. We're not discarding the entire left half-plane

Comment: Ohhh, I get it now. I had the wrong idea about how the restrictions work. Thanks a lot

Comment: What would $ f^{-1} $ be for these restrictions ?

Comment: @sleepydrmike what did you try? Also, the answer is available on Wikipedia (you have to use a piecewise definition).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Well I have $ r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} $ and $ phi = \ 
 \begin{cases} 
  0 & y = 0, x > 0 \\
  \pi & y = 0, x < 0 \\
   \pi + \arctan{\frac{y}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}}
   \end{cases}
\$

Comment: @peek-a-boo Now, what about for spherical coordinates. Could you help me out plz or point me to Wikipedia ?